# Highly-performant way to calculate height of the Unicode text in the div of fixed-width

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, word-wrap

I am looking for a highly-performant way to calculate height of the `div` of fixed width containing Unicode text (no HTML tags inside, only text!).

We've tried copying text into the hidden absolutely positioned `div` element with the copied CSS styles and getting `clientHeight` from it, but the performance of this solution doesn't satisfy our needs. The same approach is implemented by `Ext.util.TextMetrics`. For 5000+ `div` elements using this method takes about 11-12 seconds, which is a lot.

**NOTE** For our task we need to do that for each `div` though even not all of them will be initially displayed. That's because we need to know height of each individual `div` among these 5000+ elements beforehand.

We've tried creating simple word-wrapping algorithm and calculating height of the `div` by determining number of lines and then multiplying it by line height and it worked very well in terms of performance. For the same number of `div` elements on the same software / hardware configuration it takes 45 milliseconds (more than 200 times faster) - character widths are pre-calculated beforehand using slow method mentioned above. At this point we didn't take into account all word-wrapping specifics and the fact that we have Unicode text. We are thinking about making this algorithm cross-browser and take these specifics into account. We are not 100% sure that it is doable in a cross-browser fashion.

So, there are two questions:

- Is there another way to calculate text height very fast in the browser?
- Otherwise, what algorithm can we use for cross-browser word-wrapping (assuming we need to support latest Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE 9+)? What about Unicode Word Wrapping algorithm http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/?

Comment: If you only need a sum of heights of all text blocks, why not concatenate them with <br> and measure the height once?

Comment: Because additionally we also need the height of each individual `div`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I've clarified the NOTE in my question

Comment: Have you tried `window.getComputedStyle(...).height`?

Comment: @BrettZamir `window.getComputedStyle(...)` isn't supported in every main browser

Comment: Looks pretty well supported nowadays: http://caniuse.com/#search=getComputedStyle